Extend bijective maps
I'm stuck on this problem which is quite simple: given $V, W$ are two finite-dimensional spaces and $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V, W)$, if $\operatorname{null} S = \operatorname{null} T$ then there must exist some invertible(bijective) linear map $E \in \mathcal{L}(W)$ such that $S = ET$.
My approach: It is clear that
$$\dim V = \dim (\operatorname{null}S) + \dim (\operatorname{range}S) = \dim (\operatorname{null}T) + \dim (\operatorname{range} T)$$
So,
$$\operatorname{null}S = \operatorname{null} T \implies \dim (\operatorname{null} S) = \dim (\operatorname{null} T)$$
Thus, it is trivial to conclude that $\dim (\operatorname{range} S) = \dim (\operatorname{range} T)$. Since the two spaces have the same dimension, it must be true that there exists an invertible linear map $E: \operatorname{range}S \to \operatorname{range} T$. I have no idea how to approach it from here. How to extend this map to $\mathcal{W}$?

Your argument has only really made use of the fact that the nullity of $S$ and $T$ are equal. But is the conclusion necessarily true on that hypothesis alone? If not, what does that tell you about your approach?

@blargoner Yep. It's much more complicated than this.

In the following proof, we use the following lemma

Suppose $v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n}$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n}\in W$. Then there exists a unique linear map $T: V\to W$ such that $Tv_{k} = w_{k}$ for each $k\in \left\{1,\ldots, n\right\}$.

Because $\operatorname{null}S = \operatorname{null}T$ and $V, W$ are finite-dimensional, then according to the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim\operatorname{range}S = \dim\operatorname{range}T$. Let $m = \dim\operatorname{range}T$.
Let $Tv_{1}, \ldots, Tv_{m}$ be a basis of $\operatorname{range}T$ where $v_{i}\in V, i\in \left\{ 1, \ldots, m \right\}$.
$Tv_{1}, \ldots, Tv_{m}$ is a linearly independent list of vectors in $W$ and $W$ is finite-dimensional, so we can add some (can be 0) vectors to this list to obtain a basis for $W$. Let $Tv_{1}, \ldots, Tv_{m}, w_{1}, \ldots, w_{n}$ be a basis of $W$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer.
We prove that $Sv_{1}, \ldots, Sv_{m}$ is an independent list of vectors in $W$. Assume that $a_{1}Sv_{1} + \cdots + a_{m}Sv_{m} = 0$ for some scalars $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m}$, then $S(a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{m}v_{m}) = 0$, which implies $T(a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{m}v_{m}) = 0$ because $\operatorname{null}S = \operatorname{null}T$. However, $0 = T(a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{m}v_{m}) = a_{1}Tv_{1} + \cdots + a_{m}Tv_{m}$ and $Tv_{1}, \ldots, Tv_{m}$ is a linearly independent list so $a_{1} = \cdots = a_{n} = 0$. Therefore $Sv_{1}, \ldots, Sv_{m}$ is an independent list of vectors in $W$. We can add $n$ vectors in $W$ into the list $Sv_{1}, \ldots, Sv_{m}$ to obtain a basis of $W$. Let such a basis be $Sv_{1}, \ldots, Sv_{m}, z_{1}, \ldots, z_{n}$.
According to the lemma, there is a linear map $E\in\mathcal{L}(W)$ such that
$$
  \begin{cases}
      E(Tv_{i}) = Sv_{i} & \text{for $i\in \left\{1,\ldots, m\right\}$} \\
      Ew_{j} = z_{j} & \text{for $j\in \left\{1,\ldots, n\right\}$}
  \end{cases}
$$
This construction implies $E$ is an invertible linear map on $W$ as it maps a basis of $W$ to another basis of $W$. It remains to show that $S = ET$.
Let $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{p}$ be a basis of $\operatorname{null}T$ then one can prove that $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{p}, v_{1}, \ldots, v_{m}$ is a basis for $V$ (this is a part of proof for the rank-nullity theorem, you can have a look at the proof in Sheldon Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right (4th edition), which is freely available on Axler's website). For every $i \in \left\{ 1, \ldots, m \right\}$, we have $E(Tv_{i}) = Sv_{i}$ due to the definition of $E$. On the other hand, $\operatorname{null}T = \operatorname{null}S$, so $E(Tx_{j}) = 0 = Sx_{j}$ for every $j \in \left\{1, \ldots, p\right\}$. Hence $ET = S$ as they agree on a basis of $V$.

Here's another way to see it which is a little less computational. I write $N(-)$ for null space and $R(-)$ for range space.
If we let $N=V/N(S)=V/N(T)$, then by the first isomorphism theorem we have the following commutative diagram of induced maps:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
W @<S<< V @>T>> W \\
@AAA @VVV @AAA \\
R(S) @<{\cong}<{\overline{S}}< N @>{\cong}>{\overline{T}}> R(T)
\end{CD}$$
Here the arrow going down is the canonical projection, and the arrows going up are inclusions. Now we can write $W=R(S)\oplus X=R(T)\oplus Y$ where $\dim X=\dim Y$, so we can define an isomorphism $E:W\to W$ by $(\overline{S}\circ\overline{T}^{-1})\oplus F$ where $F:Y\to X$ is an arbitrary isomorphism, and $ET=S$ as can be seen from the diagram.
Note the result is not true in general if we only assume $\dim N(S)=\dim N(T)$. Also, it is not true in general that $R(S)=R(T)$.
Edit: updated to show why we can take $E$ to be an iso.
